# C# Voice Recognition using non list.Add words

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech

I'm trying to search google with whatever I say after "Search google for". Obviously I can't add everything I'll ever think of in the list of resources at the top. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here's what I have

```
    if(r == "search google for")
    {
       System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com/#q=" + (textBox1.Text));
    }
```

But I can only get r == "" responses to appear in the text box. How do I get anything after "Search google for" to appear there.

Comment: Just to be clear your problem is you have the whole string but you dont know how to show the part after "search google for" to show in a textbox?

Comment: Pretty much. I want "search google for" to trigger the event and what I say after to actually be searched. Ex: search google for cars. And it give me https://www.google.com/#q=cars back. I used a textbox because I thought it might be easier. But am ok with any method.

Comment: Just get the string and use the .contains() method to see if it contains "search google for". If so,then use .Replace() to replace search google for with an empty string,then use the results in your url. Its pretty simple really...

Comment: i think you need to check this...   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228599.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use two speech recognition engines. The first recognition engine actively searches for the word "search google for" & when it is detected, then invokes the second recognition engine which uses a dictation grammar that detects what ever you speak & out puts the result (e.Result.Text) to a textbox.

Now you can start you process

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com/#q=" + (textBox1.Text));`

I have provided you an approach which can help you achieve the desired result